# Identifying inherited classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I have an abstract class (`MagicEffect`) that has a field with enum, also there are some inherited classes (like earth, air etc..), in their constructors they specify the enum value based on which they are.

The thing is that I need to initialize other class (doesn't matter what it is) with its element, but the only thing I know is enum value. I think that the best solution would be a static method that inheritors will override with their own values. But I don't know how to make it possible and the only solution I found is to make a switch like in example below.

```
public abstract class MagicEffect : Effect
{
        protected MagicEffect(DamageElements element,...) : base(element,...) { }

        public abstract static MagicEffect GetMagicEffect(DamageElements element) //the method I want
}
```

DamageElements - enum

```
public static MagicEffect GetMagicEffect(DamageElements element)
{
    switch(element) 
    {
        case DamageElements.Fire:
            return new Fire();

        case DamageElements.Water:
            return new Water();

        case...
    }
}
```

```
namespace Game.Controller
{
    public class MagicEffectInitializer : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private List<ButtonController> _buttons;

        private void InitButtons()
        {
            foreach (var button in _buttons)
               button.Init(MagicEffect.GetMagicEffect(button.Element));
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Game.Controller
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MagicEffectButton))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MagicEffectView))]

    public sealed class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Image _selfImage;
        [SerializeField] private Sprite _spriteToSet;
        [SerializeField] private Button _button;
        [SerializeField] private DamageElements _element;

        public DamageElements Element => _element;

        public void Init(MagicEffect magicEffect)
        {
            GetComponent<MagicEffectButton>().Init(_button, magicEffect);
            GetComponent<MagicEffectView>().Init(_selfImage, _spriteToSet);
        }
    }
}
```

My question: is there a better solution without that terrible switch?

PS: Sorry for that title, I don't really know how to short this

Comment: There is not enough context to suggest a better class design.Based on the little that you have shown you probably want to implement adedicated type for each effect kind. For example `FireEffect : MagicEffect` and `WaterEffect : MagicEffect`. This eliminates the GetMagicEffect method and the enum and of course the switch statement..

Comment: @BionicCode. The `GetMagicEffect` method has a return type of `MagicEffect`. As the method returns `Fire`, `Water`, etc... there are already several subtypes inheriting from `MagicEffect`. Given the OP already has the subtypes, how do the subtypes eliminate the the `GetMagicEffect` method, enum, and switch?

Comment: @BionicCode I already have that implements and I need to decied which to choose based on their enum's value. Like class `Fire` will have value `DamageElements.Fire` in it's value. The class I need to initialize has an enum value and I need to init a field of `MagicEffec`t based on it (I want to get an instance of `Fire` class if there is `DamageElements.Fire` in it's enum field)

Comment: When you have a e.g. `Fire` then why does it need to have an identifier enum? And why would a type `Fire` return a new instance of `Fire? Even if it has to be like this, a `Fire` type would have a `CreateNew() : Fire` and a `Water` would define a `CreateNew() : Water`. In other words, each type has it's own factory method.

Comment: @MetroSmurf The problem is that there is a shared static method that knows how to create instances of all existing `MagicEffect` subtypes. This doesn't scale well. Each subtype must provide it's own implementation of `GetMagicEffect` to return an instance of its own type. This way he eliminates: 1) the static shared `GetMagicEffect` 2) The requirement to modify the switch to add new cases when new subtypes are added because this solution also eliminates 3) The switch case 4) The enum, because the identifier is the type itself. Every subtype must implement its own factory method.

Comment: MagicEffect is an abstract class. Can you give a concrete example of a magic effect? I suspect you're thinking of making subclasses like 'Petrify', 'Incinerate', etc. If that's the case, then the subclasses would know what damage element to return, so it doesn't need to be passed around as an enum

Comment: @MetroSmurf If you have an unknown type (because you only know the common base type `MagicEffect`) you donÄt have to check an identifier field in order to knwo which instance you need. You simply call `GetMagicEffect` and the implementation of the current instance will always return the correct instance.#

Comment: I need enums for some logic without using `is a` or constructions like that. I also don't need to return a new instance or smth like that, it could be a singleton. The question is how can I get any instance of `Fire` class if I have a enum `DamageElements.Fire` without using a switch, cause it would be really terrible if I would expand types of elements

Comment: Yes it is terrible. A code smell. Instead of the enum, let your type have a property of type `MagicEffect` or a collection of `MagicEffect`. Now instead of assigning an identifier enum you directly assign the appropriate `MagicEffect` instance.

Comment: I don't really got what do you mean

Comment: Please post an example where you inspect a type for the enum and then call `GetMagicEffect`. I will then modify it to give you an example. Please also show how you assign the enum value.

Comment: `public class MagicEffectInitializer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<ButtonController> _buttons;

    private void InitButtons()
    {
        foreach (var button in _buttons)
        button.Init(MagicEffect.GetMagicEffect(button.Element));
    }
}`

the class that Initializes all buttons

Comment: `public sealed class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Image _selfImage;
        [SerializeField] private Sprite _spriteToSet;
        [SerializeField] private Button _button;
        [SerializeField] private DamageElements _element;

        public DamageElements Element => _element;

        public void Init(MagicEffect magicEffect)
        {
            GetComponent<MagicEffectButton>().Init(_button, magicEffect);
            GetComponent<MagicEffectView>().Init(_selfImage, _spriteToSet);
        }
    }` 
class that need `MagicEffect`

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind to add it to your question where you can format it properly to make it easier to read?

Comment: yeah, one second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254242/discussion-between-dankisey-and-bioniccode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reflect the relationship properly. Either add an attribute to the type that allows to configure the instance to have a particular behavior (for example a `MagicEffect` property) or create a dedicated specialized type that implements the special behavior (no instance configuration required).

The following example defines a specialized type to encapsulate a particular behavior. A `FireButtonController` will provide the required `Fire` effect (of type `MagicEffect`). Instead of configuring the instance you now create the correct specialized instance:

```cs
namespace Game.Controller
{    
    public class MagicEffectInitializer : MonoBehaviour
    {
      [SerializeField] private List<ButtonController> _buttons;

      private void InitButtons()
      {
          foreach (var button in _buttons)
             button.Init();
      }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Game.Controller
{
    public sealed class FireButtonController : ButtonController
    {
        public FireButtonController()
        {
            this.Effect = new Fire();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Game.Controller
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MagicEffectButton))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MagicEffectView))]

    public sealed class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Image _selfImage;
        [SerializeField] private Sprite _spriteToSet;
        [SerializeField] private Button _button;

        //[SerializeField] private DamageElements _element;
        //public DamageElements Element => _element;

        public MagicEffect Effect { get; protected set; }

        public void Init()
        {
            GetComponent<MagicEffectButton>().Init(_button, this.Effect);
            GetComponent<MagicEffectView>().Init(_selfImage, _spriteToSet);
        }
    }
}

// Instead of configuring the ButtonController 
// by assigning a e.g. `DamageElements.Fire` effect identifier
// you directly create a specialed instance that uses the desired effect.
// The context that creates the ButtonController obviously has all the required knowledge.
var buttonController = new FireButtonController() ;
```